# How to display the second half of text on HTML select drop-down list?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-select

As the title states, I have a select drop-down list with fixed width 80px like this:

[image]

```
<select id="dd_country_code_2" name="dd_country_code_2" style="width: 120px;  height: 23px;">
    <option value="SEL">(Country code)</option>
    <option value="AF">Afghanistan ‏(‎+93)</option>
    <option value="AL">Albania ‏(‎+355)</option>
    <option value="DO">Dominican Republic ‏(‎+1)</option>
    <option value="FK">Falkland Islands ‏(‎+500)</option>
</select>
```

When a user selects an option, this is the result:

[image]

But, instead of this, I want the second half of the text to displayed in the 80px of the list, so the user to be able to see clearly its country code.

For example:

[image]

How can I achieve this?

Comment: That looks really bad, as a UI, like a non pro website. Why do you want that?

Comment: I want this to avoid any mistakes by the users (to select its country codes instead of writing them)... Also, the (full) list has been taken from a template, so I can't re-format it...

Comment: Why the need of a fixed width? ... That's why it looks very bad, when it is to narrow

Comment: If you really can't go with something more clean UI, pick Mario's solution, its a good one ... updated with your items so you see how it looks

Comment: I think I can't make more clean UI from this! My space is kind of limited. Also, consider that there are big country names like this: "Saint Helena, Ascension and Tristan da Cunha ‏(‎+290)". What do you propose? To make the list broader (like 500px) just for 1 or 2 big country names??

Comment: "Why the need of a fixed width?" - Is there any dynamic-width <select> element which can I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the width is an issue, here is another way, where when the list item is to big, it gets cut off.

*Updated, using a pseudo to hold the down arrow so one can make the `input` full width/height*

```js
(function() {
  document.querySelector('select').addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    var val = e.target.options[ e.target.selectedIndex ].text.split('(');
    if (val[0].length > 12) {
      val[0] = val[0].slice(0, 10) + '...';
    }    
    e.target.nextElementSibling.value = val.join('(');
  });
})();
```

```css
.selectable {
  position:relative;
  background-color:white;
  border:solid grey 1px;
  width:120px;
  height:18px;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.selectable:after {
  content: '\25BC';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width:14px;
  height:18px;
  line-height:20px;
  pointer-events: none;
  font-size: 10px;
  text-align: center
}
.selectable select {
  position:absolute;
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
  font-size: inherit;
  border:none;
  width:120px;
  margin:0;
}
.selectable input {
  position:absolute;
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  padding:1px;
  font-size: inherit;
  border:none;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.selectable select:focus, .selectable input:focus {
  outline:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="selectable">
  <select>
    <option value="SEL">(Country code)</option>
    <option value="AF">Afghanistan (+93)</option>
    <option value="AL">Albania (+355)</option>
    <option value="DO">Dominican Republic (+1)</option>
    <option value="FK">Falkland Islands (+500)</option>
  </select>
  <input type="text" name="countrycode" value="(Country code)" />
</div>
```

Comment: Firstly, thank you for your version of the solution, but this solution has two main problems for me: 1) The list is taken "as is" from a template, it is very wide, so I can't edit all records one-by-one by hand and 2) It is too difficult for the user to know that must put his mouse over the name and to wait until the tooltip being displayed to understand what the dots hides... I can't understand why @MarioD 's solution doesn't work in me...

Comment: @MinimalTech Yes, I understand both issues, so what you need is a small width when selected, but during selection, you want to show it all, correct? .. and if yes, there might be a way, using script, so let me know and I look at it.

Comment: Do you refer to something like a "dynamic width <select> element"? If yes, I think I do not want it (after consideration) because something like this will broke the style of my page/UI.. All I want is a fixed, 120px width, <select> that can behave like the description I gave in the pictures (in my question) -or- something like MarioD's solution which works perfectly inside Stack Overflow's code snippet but it works with the half functionality in me and I can't understand why!!

Comment: @MinimalTech Updated my answer with a completely new solution.

Comment: Wow, very good approach! Never came into my mind to do something like this, with a textbox over a <select>! But it has some minor - visual problems: 1) Some streaks appears near the end of the textbox when you select a country (like the start of a letter or a half letter) and 2) the height of the textbox is not 100% the same as the select's (the contents of the <select> are visible behind of the textbox - at the bottom). Can these problems be fixed? (Also, check for visual compatibility with IE 11 in addition to Firefox..)

Comment: @MinimalTech Updated, altered the input's width/height a little, looks better now .. you can make your own adjustments how you want it to look. Since form fields often have minor differences between browsers, you might need to target them individually.

Comment: LGSon, sorry for any inclonvinience that may I cause, but for me the result is the same... Check for yourself (with Firefox): 1) load your code on a page and see the list with "(Country code)" selected. You will see 3 semi-characters (10% of a character visible) at the bottom of the text input. Also, 2) check the "Dominican Republic (+1)" from the list and see the streak at the end of the text input...

Comment: @MinimalTech This [fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/hn7huf5g/) works in FF and IE11, but the stack snippet does have those issues ... which kind of proves my point. So when you use it in your own code you'll then likely need to make minor adjustments as browsers in general render form fields slightly different, and that is something I can't do for you.

Comment: This fiddle demo and the SO Code Snippet has the same behavior (at least in this case). Both of them has the same issues that I have mentioned before. Please, look more closely. Or, compare it with a new single <select> list (side-by-side) to see the visual differences.

Comment: @MinimalTech I made a final update of my answer ... any further adjustments you need to figure yourself. The update is tested in Chrome/FF/Edge/IE11 with no issues. ... it is so good it should be worth both an accept,  an up-vote and a bounty :)

Comment: Excellent implementation!! Of course this considered as an accepted answer! I gave you an up-vote too. If I had enough reputation I would put also a bounty... Thank you very much for your time!

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `direction: rtl;` css property.

```js
(function() {
  document.querySelector('select').addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    e.target.style.direction = 'ltr';
    if(e.target.selectedIndex > 0) {
      e.target.style.direction = 'rtl';
    };
  });
})();
```

```css
#dd_country_code_2 {
  width: 120px;
}
```

```html
<select id="dd_country_code_2" name="dd_country_code_2" style="height: 23px;">
    <option value="SEL">(Country code) </option>
    <option value="AF">Afghanistan (+93) </option>
    <option value="AL">Albania (+355) </option>
    <option value="DO">Dominican Republic (+1) </option>
    <option value="FK">Falkland Islands (+500)</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Looks very good, but I can't make it work on my website. I put the script inside <script type="text/javascript"> ... </script> tags, inside <body>, but it doesn't run correctly (I am using Firefox 45.0.1)... If I select a country from the list, the arrow goes to the left and the text becomes for ex. "(+355) Albania", like your first edition... It has not the functionality of the "code snippet" of Stack Overflow..

Comment: @MinimalTech Make sure the script is in the end of the body, after the actual select.

Comment: I have put it in the end of the body, yes! Please, see yourself: http://we.tl/LxlCgI2xur (download the html file)..

Comment: @MinimalTech I tried and it actually doesn't work ... I also downloaded the SO snippet and it deosn't work either ... interesting ... I will have a look at another alternative later, will notify you when done.